# Использование Java кода в JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Пишу веб-приложение в NetBeans. Есть БД MySQL, откуда получаю данные и передаю их в скрипт для дальнейшей обработки. Получение происходит в JSP посредством использования `<% java code %>`.
Хотел узнать, насколько правильно в JSP писать Java-код. Я новенький в вебе и вообще в программировании.

Comment: Зачем вы откатили правку? Это вполне можно расценивать как вандализм. И по самому вопросу: писать логику в .jsp-файлах - это не дело.

Comment: Даже автор книжки Java Servlet Programming критиковал JSP за то, что JSP провоцирует/заставляет программистов смешивать код и html. Правильным считается использование JSP в качестве шаблона представления в MVC в лучшем случае (как например в Spring Framework)